# Running deep cycle 12 V batteries in parallel: should I use two 100 Ah batteries or six 50 Ah batteries?

Tags: batteries

I have two series 27 deep cycle, 12 V 100 Ah each, running parallel. Would it be better to run those, or six 12 V 50 Ah in parallel, since they take up about the same amount of space and I would gain a extra 100 Ah?

Comment: Check the datasheets (which you haven't linked) for charge and discharge current ratings of each solution. A heavy duty high current 200Ah solution can do things a light duty low current 300Ah can't. (And that difference may explain higher capacity in smaller space). Then decide which meets your needs (which you haven't told us).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I've also have linked a 500 watt inverter, that is only going to run my 105 watt ice maker, gotta have my scotch on the rocks while camping

Answer (score 5):

The two Group 27 100 Ah batteries in parallel will give you 200  Ah.

The six 12 V 50 Ah batteries in parallel would give you 300 Ah, or 50% more storage capacity.

Check the space requirements carefully - I'd expect the six 50 Ah batteries to take up about 50% more space than the two Group 27s, as well as giving 50% more storage.